Blender not showing colors for point cloud
Why is blender how showing colors for my point cloud? I have tried changing to material preview etc but its still black.

import os
import sys
import bpy
from glob import glob
from plyfile import PlyData  # Required to read the .ply file header

# Global variable to store the mesh file paths
ply_filenames = []

# Remove all existing objects from the scene (clean up from previous frames)
def clear_scene():
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
    bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)

# Function to check if the .ply file contains color information
def ply_has_color(ply_file):
    """Check if the .ply file contains color information."""
    ply_data = PlyData.read(ply_file)
    vertex_element = ply_data['vertex']  # Access the vertex element directly
    has_color = all(color in vertex_element.data.dtype.names for color in ['red', 'green', 'blue'])
    return has_color

# Load the point cloud and handle color information if present
def load_current_frame(scene):
    """Callback function triggered on frame change."""
    current_frame = scene.frame_current
    if current_frame < len(ply_filenames):
        # Clear the previous frame's objects
        clear_scene()

        ply_file = ply_filenames[current_frame]
        print(f"Loading point cloud for frame {current_frame}: {ply_file}")

        # Check if the .ply file has color information
        if ply_has_color(ply_file):
            print(f".ply file {ply_file} contains color information.")
            # Import the PLY point cloud with color data
            bpy.ops.import_mesh.ply(filepath=ply_file)

            # Get the imported object (the point cloud)
            imported_object = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
            
            # Scale the point cloud
            imported_object.scale = (0.001, 0.001, 0.001)

        else:
            print(f".ply file {ply_file} does NOT contain color information, but no external image is available.")
            # Handle this case if needed (e.g., throw an error or log it)
        
    else:
        print(f"No point cloud available for frame {current_frame}")


# Main execution
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    argv = sys.argv
    argv = argv[argv.index("--") + 1:]
        
    # Path to point cloud (.ply) files
    ply_filenames = sorted(glob(os.path.join(argv[0], "*.ply")))

    # Check if any files were found
    if not ply_filenames:
        print(f"No .ply files found in the directory: {argv[0]}")
        sys.exit(1)

    # Clear default scene
    bpy.ops.wm.read_factory_settings(use_empty=True)

    # Register the frame change handler
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.clear()  # Clear any existing handlers
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(load_current_frame)

    print("Point cloud visualization setup complete.")

